# IIS preload application

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, iis, iis-7

I have followed the steps here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/whats-new-in-iis-8/iis-80-application-initialization to preload my IIS application, which works well, but my question is how can I refresh the browser after IIS has finished compiling and is ready to serve application?

Specifically on that page referred above it states: **You can continure refreshing the page in your wb browser and observe that about eight seconds later (simulated with a thread sleep in the sample application's global.asax) you receive the "real" content for default.aspx with a white background.**

I would like to simulate that thread sleep and refresh automagically when IIS is finished and ready. I do not want my user to have to continually refresh the page. I want to just serve the application when finished through a thread sleep.

--UPDATE--

I have tried to implement @rene comment, however the splash page that is served by IIS seems like a 'parsed' version of index.html, and I am unable to load any external javascript/css that is located within the application which then forces me to use a cdn for jQuery/Bootstrap/etc.

Example Html Splash page

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=11">
    <title>FamLink - Pro</title>
    <!--CONTENT FROM APPLICATION WILL NOT BE SERVED-->
    <!--<link href="/App/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="/App/Scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/App/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>-->

    <!--CONTENT FROM CDN IS SERVED-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>-->
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please wait while application is loading....</h1>
    <!--DOES NOT WORK (receive a 404)--> 
    <img src="Content/Images/468.gif" />
</body>
</html>
```

My web.config section

```
<system.webServer>
 <applicationInitialization
       remapManagedRequestsTo="index.html"
       skipManagedModules="true" >
      <add initializationPage="/App" />
    </applicationInitialization>    
</system.webServer>
```

My applicationHost.config section

```
<applicationPools>
 <add name="MainNode" autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0" startMode="AlwaysRunning">
                <processModel identityType="SpecificUser" userName="*****" password="****" idleTimeout="00:00:00" />
            </add>
</applicationPools>

<sites>
<site name="MainNode" id="7" serverAutoStart="true">
                <application path="/App" applicationPool="MainNodeAppPool" preloadEnabled="true">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="C:\inetpub\sites\MainNode" />
                </application>
</site>
</sites>
```

Is anyone else trying to implement this solution? and if so how to accomplish my task? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use an AJAX call from JavaScript in the browser to call an endpoint on your server. Continue until you get the new version and then refresh.

Comment: @rene You say "until you get the new version"... how do I know? Is there not a method like "Init" (which gets called once per user) on Global.asax that I could leverage a thread sleep on?